# Will CSRF token warning prevent devise from having a current user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use an jquery ajax to update a TimeSlot model from a page showing a campaign. The Campaign is a signup sheet with columns of days and rows of time_slots. The user can join a timeslot by clicking the correct checkbox.

When I implemented this feature several months ago I wasn't getting any errors. Now, I'm getting a 500 error saying there is an internal server error. I did some digging and it appears the error is caused by devise's `current_user` method not returning a value. There is a CSRF warning in the log. This causes a NilClass to be returned and a mismatched type exception to be thrown. This causes the 500 error.

Do I need to supply CSRF token information in my AJAX call? If I do, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can always skip the csrf check for the controller action that your ajax is calling with:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :some_action
```

Comment: Hm. I could, but is that the best approach?